# Java Selenium WebDriver - correct exception handling techniques when unable to locate window

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Java and Selenium to automate some test cases. This involves loading a single page with search results and iterating over each 100-1000 links on that single page. Setting the test config to only check about 100 results will usually be okay, but anything higher than that and at some point a NoSuchWindowException is thrown(subclass of WebDriverException). This happens when I switch from the the parent handle to the newly opened window handle.

I've written a try-catch statement inside a do while loop to catch the exception and retry the procedure... However, whatever I try, Selenium will not play nice, and my code execution abruptly ends.. :( Here is the code:

```
boolean completed = false;
    do{
        try{
            //click the search result
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath string")).click();
            //switch to the new window
            for(String winHandle: driver.getWindowHandles()){
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            }
            //for our test we need to save the source       
            source = driver.getPageSource();
            //close popup window and and switch back to the parent handle
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            completed = true;
        }catch(WebDriverException ex){
            System.out.println("something went wrong while switching windows... retrying");
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
        }
    }while(!completed);
```

I've experimented with various approaches when an exception is caught. For example, i tried saving the parent url, using driver.quit() followed by trying to restart the driver. However, then Selenium complained about I wasn't able to start the Firefox driver after calling driver.quit()...

Any ideas how to better handle the catch part of my code?

Comment: Exception is thrown from your catch block. You don't catch it and your app exits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution thanks to the comments left by Tala.

I simply removed the following statements from the catch block:

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

Now the the catch block is not generating a separate uncaught exception by itself and the loop correctly does it work retrying the previous code...